# How to use discontinuous range in SUMIF

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning to use SUMIF in excel. Usually in the first argument in this formula is a continuous range (something like this A1:F1). But now I really need to choose something like this: A1, C1, E1 due to the data set format. Can I do somthing like this in Excel? or even VBA. I also tried to use INDIRECT but it only allows me to fill in one row. If I do an autofill down the row number won't be changed. Here is the formula I used:

```
   SUM((SUMIF(INDIRECT({"A1","C1","E1","G1","I1","K1","M1","O1","Q1","S1"}),"<"&V1,INDIRECT({"B1","D1","F1","H1","J1","L1","N1","P1","R1","T1"}))))
```

Anyone know how to do this for the whole column? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What sort of values do you have in these cells? I know the example shows data in row 1 but is that the real setup you have - if you have any header row which can be used to distinguish the relevant columns then there might be a simpler way.......

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't propose this as a very sensible solution but you can make the formula "draggable" by using this version - `=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT({"A","C","E","G","I","K","M","O","Q","S"}&ROWS(A$1:A1)),"<"&V1,INDIRECT({"B","D","F","H","J","L","N","P","R","T"}&ROWS(A$1:A1))))` - confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: @barryhoudini I have date values in A, C, E....and have numeric values in B, D, F. I made up this data in this example so the really one has column names for both date and number. Thanks for giving me this brilliant solution. Maybe I should use A2, C2..to be a better example.

Comment: If row 1 has "Date" in all the date columns you can use a much simpler formula like this: `=SUMIFS(B2:T2,A2:S2,"<"&V2,A$1:S$1,"Date")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clever idea to use a discontinuous range (also known as a multi-area range).

**But it won't work.**

Yes, you can create a dicontinuous range using range syntax `SUMIF((A1,C1,E1,G1),...)` a named range (select the cells and then insert->range->define), the `UNION()` function, or `INDIRECT()`, but none of them will work, because `SUMIF()` doesn't support discontinuous ranges.

So you have to cheat. Your question has been asked before, as I found by googling "sumif discontinuous":

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/226429-sumif-discontinuous-cells.html

Adapting Oaktree's answer we get:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN($A1:$S1),2)=1),--($A1:$S1>V1),$B1:$T1)
```

How does it work? It creates three lists, and finds the value of each element in each list, then multiplies them together. The first parameter is 1 for the odd columns and 0 for the even columns. The second parameter is 1 if it's greater than V1, otherwise 0. The third parameter is the values one column over.

Comment: Thanks this is a really really fantastic cheating. Everything sorted

Comment: @AnotherParker I agree that this is a better method but it's not true to say that the formula quoted in the formula doesn't work - it does if "array entered" - `INDIRECT` doesn't really create a discontinuous range here, it creates an array of ranges

Comment: @AnotherParker BTW what is -- in the formula? Thanks

Comment: The `--` is a key innovation i use of `SUMPRODUCT()`: it lets you use  boolean values (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) by turning them into `1` or `0` respectively, so they'll behave as you want when it multiplies everything together.

Comment: @barryhoudini yes you're right, I had forgotten that many of the Excel builtin worksheet functions try harder if you enter them as array formulas (Control-Shift-Enter or CSE For short). The reason is I really prefer `SUMPRODUCT` as it seems to be just as flexible without making the function hard to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SUM` and `FILTER` which would be a shorter formula to create. The below would add up the values in column B and D if the row in column A is equal to 'Box', so would be 18 (1 + 2 + 7 + 8).

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:D,A:A="Box"))
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Box | 1 | Red | 7 |
| Box | 2 | Green | 8 |
| Circle | 3 | Blue | 9 |
| Circle | 4 | Red | 10 |
| Triangle | 5 | Green | 11 |
| Triangle | 6 | Blue | 12 |