# SUMPRODUCT() handling arrays in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, range, conditional-statements

I have three arrays A, B, and A - B = C. They are broken into columns and formatted in excel like:

`A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C... D, E`

I want to sum all C>0 = D, and sum of all C<0 = E. The problem is that C is broken up for easy human readability, so I only want to call every third column.

My solution:

Following a variation on the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356593/how-to-use-discontinuous-range-in-sumif) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/226429-sumif-discontinuous-cells.html), and a simple test array of data:

```
    1    0   1   1
    1    1   0   1
   -1   -1  -1   1
    0   -1  -1   0
   -1   -1   1   0
    1    1   0   1
```

I will pull out the even columns and do the conditional sums:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1),2)=0)*(A1:D1>0),A1:D1)
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1),2)=0)*(A1:D1<0),A1:D1)
```

Which produces the correct result:

```
    1  0
    2  0
    1 -1
    0 -1
    0 -1
    2  0
```

But I am absolutely baffled as to *why* this works. For one thing, I didn't put in the double negative (--), so upon getting a "TRUE" or "FALSE" value, the formula should have spit an error at me. For another, this works just fine even though I'm not running it as a CSE array function in excel. And the part I get least of all is the arguments for `SUMPRODUCT()`.

`MOD()` is just acting as a filter for the conditional, that I get, but I don't understand how it's handling A1:D1 when all it gets from COLUMN is a single number. `COLUMN(A1:D1)` just returns a single scalar value in excel, the first column in the range, in this case 1. How is that being turned into the needed array [1, 3], especially since I'm not using CSE?

Comment: Formulas tab > Evaluate Formula https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT is naturally an Array type formula which is why you do not need the CSE:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A6,B1:B6)
```

This will iterate and do A1*B1+A2*B2+...

So using this functionality we can do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1),2)))
```

Which will iterate through the columns and return: `2` MOD(1,2)+MOD(2,2)+...

The reason you do not need the double unary(`--`) is because you have the `*` in the expression.  Any math done on a Boolean(`TRUE/FALSE`) will turn it to its Bit (`1/0`).

The `--` is short hand for `-1 * -1 *`

You would need the `--` if you did this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(A1:D1),2)=0),--(A1:D1>0),A1:D1)
```

So with this you would end up multiplying a series of 1's and 0's against the series in A1:D1.

When either is false it will return 0 and 0 times anything is 0.

So only when both are TRUE or 1 does the value in the corresponding cell get added to the iterating sum.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I wasn't aware functions could natively be CSE (only been  using excel for about a week). And seeing the sumproduct written as 3 arguments makes it *much* clearer what's going on.