# Non-adjacent cells in a formula causing too many arguments

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to get an average of some numbers, excluding cells that are equal to zero.

formula is currently:
=AVERAGEIF((B3,D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3,P3),"<>0")

Excel is telling me there's too many arguments so is there a way I can tell it that cell range is the range I'm after just because they're not all adjacent cells excel is throwing a wobbly and I can't seem to workout how.

Comment: You're missing your 3rd argument in `AVERAGEIF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIF(B3:P3,"<>0")
```

should give you what you want. As described in the help of AVERAGEIF:

> Cells in range that contain TRUE or FALSE are ignored.
>
> If a cell in average_range is an empty cell, AVERAGEIF ignores it.
>
> If range is a blank or text value, AVERAGEIF returns the #DIV0! error value.
>
> If a cell in criteria is empty, AVERAGEIF treats it as a 0 value.

As long as there is at least one cell with a number in the range you have specified, it will return the average of the range according to the criteria you have set.

Comment: That formula is still missing the 3rd parameter of the `average_range`.

Comment: `average_range`is optional; defaults to the specified `range`(B3:P3 in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the help, the issue was the cells I wanted to get an average of weren't adjacent - so using a range like B3:P3 would include unwanted/different data in the average. I have since edited the layout so it would work with the AVERAGEIF function, like you've recommended! Thanks all.

Comment: Chaning the layout of the data is definetly the best choice. If that were not an option, you could potentially adapt this answer to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356593/how-to-use-discontinuous-range-in-sumif/29356928